# How to write a program to rename mp4 files to match the name of srt files?

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, file-rename

So I have downloaded the mp4 and srt files for "Introduction to computer networks" course from Coursera. But there is slight discrepancy between the names of mp4 and srt files.

The file name samples are following:

```
1 - 1 - 1-1 Goals and Motivation (1253).mp4
1 - 1 - 1-1 Goals and Motivation (12_53).srt
1 - 2 - 1-2 Uses of Networks (1316).mp4
1 - 2 - 1-2 Uses of Networks (13_16).srt
1 - 3 - 1-3 Network Components (1330).mp4
1 - 3 - 1-3 Network Components (13_30).srt
1 - 4 - 1-4 Sockets (1407).mp4
1 - 4 - 1-4 Sockets (14_07).srt
1 - 5 - 1-5 Traceroute (0736).mp4
1 - 5 - 1-5 Traceroute (07_36).srt
1 - 6 - 1-6 Protocol Layers (2225).mp4
1 - 6 - 1-6 Protocol Layers (22_25).srt
1 - 7 - 1-7 Reference Models (1409).mp4
1 - 7 - 1-7 Reference Models (14_09).srt
1 - 8 - 1-8 Internet History (1239).mp4
1 - 8 - 1-8 Internet History (12_39).srt
1 - 9 - 1-9 Lecture Outline (0407).mp4
1 - 9 - 1-9 Lecture Outline (04_07).srt
2 - 1 - 2-1 Physical Layer Overview (09_27).mp4
2 - 1 - 2-1 Physical Layer Overview (09_27).srt
2 - 2 - 2-2 Media (856).mp4
2 - 2 - 2-2 Media (8_56).srt
2 - 3 - 2-3 Signals (1758).mp4
2 - 3 - 2-3 Signals (17_58).srt
2 - 4 - 2-4 Modulation (1100).mp4
2 - 4 - 2-4 Modulation (11_00).srt
2 - 5 - 2-5 Limits (1243).mp4
2 - 5 - 2-5 Limits (12_43).srt
2 - 6 - 2-6 Link Layer Overview (0414).mp4
2 - 6 - 2-6 Link Layer Overview (04_14).srt
2 - 7 - 2-7 Framing (1126).mp4
2 - 7 - 2-7 Framing (11_26).srt
2 - 8 - 2-8 Error Overview (1745).mp4
2 - 8 - 2-8 Error Overview (17_45).srt
2 - 9 - 2-9 Error Detection (2317).mp4
2 - 9 - 2-9 Error Detection (23_17).srt
2 - 10 - 2-10 Error Correction (1928).mp4
2 - 10 - 2-10 Error Correction (19_28).srt
```

I want to **rename the mp4 files** to match srt files so that vlc can automatically load the subtitles when I play the videos. What someone discuss be algorithms to do this? You can also provide solution code in any language as I am familiar with many programming languages. But python and c++ are preferable.

**Edit**:
Thanks to everyone who replied. I know it is easier to rename the srt files than the other way around. But I think it will be more interesting to rename the mp4 files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Err, just [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) all `.str` and remove the underscore? That's like ten lines of python, at most.

Comment: The algorithm is simple: for each mp4 file, find its corresponding srt file(1) and rename it to the same name the mp4 file has but with another extension. You should just go ahead and try it. (1) shouldn't be hard since you have identifying information in the first fields of the filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution in python.

The job is simple if you make the following assumptions:

1. all files are in the same folder
2. you have the same number of srt and mp4 files in the directory
3. all srt are ordered alphabetically, all mp4 are ordered alphabetically

Note I do not assume anything about the actual names (e.g. that you only need to remove underscores).

So you don't need any special logic for matching the files, just go one-by-one.

```
import os, sys, re
from glob import glob

def mv(src, dest):
    print 'mv "%s" "%s"' % (src, dest)
    #os.rename(src, dest)  # uncomment this to actually rename the files

dir = sys.argv[1]

vid_files = sorted(glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.mp4')))
sub_files = sorted(glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.srt')))
assert len(sub_files) == len(vid_files), "lists of different lengths"

for vidf, subf in zip(vid_files, sub_files):
    new_vidf = re.sub(r'\.srt$', '.mp4', subf)
    if vidf == new_vidf:
        print '%s OK' % ( vidf, )
        continue
    mv(vidf, new_vidf)
```

Again, this is just a quick script.  Suggested improvements:

1. support different file extensions
2. use a better cli, e.g. `argparse`
3. support taking multiple directories
4. support test-mode (don't actually rename the files)
5. better error reporting (instead of using `assert`)
6. more advanced: support undoing

Comment: It seems like the OP wanted to have the `mp4`s renamed instead of the `srt`. I edited your answer since it was the most appropriate for this task.

Comment: Thanks shx2 and @Zeta. This script does exactly what I want and thanks for the suggested improvements. I will try to make the improvements later.

Answer (score 2):

If all those files really follow this scheme the Python implementation is almost trivial:

```
import glob, os

for subfile in glob.glob("*.srt")
    os.rename(subfile, subfile.replace("_",""))
```

If your mp4 also contain underscores you want to add an additional loop for them.

Answer (score 2):

`for f in *.srt; do mv $f ${f%_}; done`

Comment: While valid, this will only work with a `bash`-like environment. It can't be used on Windows :(.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an implementation of what Zeta said :)

```
import os;
from path import path;
for filename in os.listdir('.'):        
    extension = os.path.splitext(path(filename).abspath())[1][1:]
    if extension == 'srt':        
        newName = filename.replace('_','');
        print 'Changing\t' + filename + ' to\t' + newName;
        os.rename(filename,newName);
print 'Done!'
```